# iOS Facebook SDK Retrieve Friends List

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Facebook iOS SDK and get a list of all the friends of the logged in user.  I have already requested the permission to access the "user_friends" as shown below:

```
 login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","user_friends"], from: self) {
```

And in my different view controller I try to fetch the friends list.

```
guard let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/99999999923232321/friends", parameters: nil, httpMethod:"GET") else {
            fatalError("Unable to create the Facebook Request")
        }

        request.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

            print(result)

        })
```

I get the error back:

```
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)"
```

Comment: You cannot get user_friends as per facebook documentation, if you have canvas application then you can get all friend list of logged in user. By now you can get only friends who used your application

Answer (score 0):

You should create request with "me" parameter.And another thing,you should create empty parameter for just in case. Request should be like this:

```
let parametersForFriends = ["fields": "name,id"]
let graphRequestForFriends = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: parametersForFriends)
```

**EDIT**

When you try to get friends like this,Facebook only return users friends only  which is already login to your application. I mean if none of this user's friends login to your application,response will be empty.

Hope this help